# MS Word, remove header if heading 1 is present

Tags: microsoft-word, headers, layout

Is it possible to disable the header on any page that has a Header 1?

Comment: do you mean remove all Heading 1 styles from a document or switch off the Page Header where a Heading 1 style exists on a page?

Comment: @Shevek No, I don't want a page header when a heading is present on the page

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this automatically will be to write a macro. This is a bit beyond my macro skills, but this is the process you will need to follow as the only way to switch off a Header or Footer on a single page is by using Sections

1. Loop through each page
2. Check for a `Header 1` style
3. Insert `Section Break` at top of current page
4. Insert `Section Break` at top of next page
5. Switch off `Same As Previous` for BOTH the newly created sections
6. Clear the `Header` of the current page

You may be able to get some help creating a macro on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)

You could also follow this process manually.

**EDIT: In response to Comment:**

Not quite -  the "different footer and header" setting is only applicable to "odd and even" or "first page" e.g.:

```
page 1 has header a, all others have header b
```

or

```
even pages have header a, odd pages have header b
```

The only way to mix and match headers is to use section breaks with `Same As Previous` switched off

Comment: Well with a section break, you chance the page setup to be "different footer and header", anyways, I was hoping there is an easier way of doing this :(

Comment: @dassouki - I have updated my answer with a response to your comment as I needed more formatting than a comment allows!

Comment: When you're doing a new section, the first page of that section is considered first page

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it to see if it works, but in the "Replace" feature (as in Find and Replace) there is a way to search for a style including Heading 1. You could search by style and Replace with nothing or whatever you like instead.